# Pytest assertion error is blocking the test execution

Tags: python, api, automation, pytest

I have the following code which reads data from an external excel and hit the post request but whenever I encountered an assertion error with 1 row data set from the excel, the for loop stops and the rest of the excel rows are not taken for execution. The program execution gets stopped at that point. How to overcome this?
My requirement is if out of 10 data set(10 rows in excel), the assertion fails in the 5th one for example, it should execute the program with remaining data sets and at the end mark the test case execution as FAILED.

def test_1A():

```
url_plan = getCOnfigurations()['API']['URL'] + APIResources.endpoints_plans
classic_sum_values = [200000, 300000, 400000]
payload_plan = open('C:/Users/aprat/PycharmProjects/RSAHealthPytest/PayLoads/plans/1A.json','r')
json_payload_plan = json.loads(payload_plan.read())

obj = Library.BaseClass("C:/Users/aprat/PycharmProjects/RSAHealthPytest/TestData/1A/TestData1A.xlsx","sheet1")
col = obj.fetch_column_count()
row = obj.fetch_row_count()
key_age = obj.fetch_key_names()
key_dob = obj.fetch_key_names()
key_sum = obj.fetch_key_names()
key_ten = obj.fetch_key_names()
key_pr_mem_age = obj.fetch_key_names()

for i in range(2, row+1):
    datadriven_json_data_plan = obj.update_request_with_data_plan1A(i,json_payload_plan,key_age,key_dob,key_pr_mem_age,key_sum,key_ten)
    a1_age = json_payload_plan['payload']['data']['insured'][0]['age']
    a1_dob = json_payload_plan['payload']['data']['insured'][0]['dob']
    prim_mem_age = json_payload_plan['payload']['data']['primary_member_age']
    tot_sum = json_payload_plan['payload']['data']['sum_insured']
    tenure = json_payload_plan['payload']['data']['tenure']
    response = requests.post(url_plan, json=datadriven_json_data_plan,)
    json_response_plan = response.json()
    print(json_response_plan)
    if int(tenure) == 1 or int(tenure) == 2 or int(tenure) == 3:
        if int(tot_sum) in classic_sum_values:
            if int(18) <= int(a1_age) <= int(50):
                print(json_response_plan[0]['article_code'])
                try:
                    assert int(json_response_plan[0]['premium']) > int(1)
                    assert int(json_response_plan[0]['term']) == int(tenure)
                    assert int(json_response_plan[0]['validity']) == int(tenure)
                    assert int(json_response_plan[0]['sa']) == int(tot_sum)
                except Exception as e:
                    json_data = datadriven_json_data_plan
                    sys.stdout = open("plans_classic_1A.log", "a")
                    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
                    traceback.print_tb(tb)
                    tb_info = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
                    filename, line, func, text = tb_info[-1]
                    print('An error occurred on line {} in statement {}'.format(line, text))
                    print("Test failure due to assertion error")
                    print("adult1 age=" + " " + str(a1_age))
                    print("sum insured=" + " " + str(tot_sum))
                    print("tenure=" + " " + str(tenure))
                    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2))
                    print("**************************************************************************")
                    raise e
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are raising the error, allowing it to pass out of the loop. Remove the `raise e` line at the end of your code and add some kind of error handling/logging to pass through a report.

A list that you append to is probably the simplest solution, but using the Python `logging` package will be a better long-term solution.

Edit: based on your previous comment, set a flag that defaults to True/success. If it fails once, it is automatically set to False/failure.

For example:

```py
def test1a():
    successFlag = True
...
    except Exception as e:
        successFlag = False

    return successFlag
```

Comment: removing the raise e line, but that time the whole test execution is showing as PASS in the test report which is misleading.

Comment: Added an edit with a flag to track.

Comment: This approach didnt work out for me. After the execution, the test case status is showing as PASSED

Comment: Nothing in your code shows where you set the pass/fail functionality - please provide additional details beyond "it is failing".